# Post Message On Facebook wall without showing Login page again

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing an application in Android to post a message in users Facebook wall.Lots of examples and Links are available but the problem is that.

In My application the user will Login to his/her's Facebook accounts at the time of installation only.Then whenever he/she presses the a particular button customized Message have to be posted in Facebook wall without asking to login again.

In the available examples the login page will appear and user has to login again. help...

EDIT: i am again Clarifying My idea.My application is to post the users location into Facebook wall to get help when the user presses the Button.This is used as security application.So its not fair to login to facebook to post the message at the Time of Usage.

How to do this Please Help..
Thanks.

Comment: What if the user change his password on facebook website?

Comment: You need to use [user access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#usertokens)..Short-lived tokens usually have a lifetime of about an `hour` or `two`, while long-lived tokens usually have a lifetime of about `60 days` .Mobile apps that use Facebook's mobile SDKs get long-lived tokens

Comment: Brontok : Have to show password error message..

Answer (score 0):

You should save login and password in SharedPreferences.

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString("access_token",facebook.getAccessToken());
editor.putLong("access_expires",facebook.getAccessExpires());
editor.commit();
```

See [this for SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: @user3349680, https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/192937658/FacebookExample.zip download this example and replace your Facebook APP_ID in two places(LoginFacebookActivity.java, MainActivity.java) hope this will help you.

Comment: @user3349680 , Hey accept or reply to the answer. Is your problem cleared?

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the following code, which perform login to facebook,post to facebook wall, showing profile image, showing friends list and logout.... hope you will enjoy :)

```
//   Add this code to your MainActivity
package com.example.abc;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;
import com.facebook.android.Util;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Your Facebook APP ID
private static String APP_ID = "your app id"; // Replace with your App
                                                    // ID
ArrayList<String> friends_list;
ListView lv;
// Instance of Facebook Class
public static Facebook facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
public static AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
public SharedPreferences mPrefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
public static  String username;
// Buttons
static Button btnFbLogin;
static Button btnFbGetProfile;
static Button btnPostToWall;
static Button btnShowFriends;
static Button btnLogout;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ImageView user_picture; 
URL img_value = null;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    user_picture= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    btnFbLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fblogin);
    btnFbGetProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_get_profile);
    btnPostToWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_fb_post_to_wall);
    btnShowFriends = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_show_friends);
    btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);
    mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    friends_list = new ArrayList<String>();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    /**
     * Login button Click event
     * */
    btnFbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Image Button", "button Clicked");
            loginToFacebook();
        }
    });

    /**
     * Getting facebook Profile info
     * */
    btnFbGetProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // getFriends();
            getProfileInformation();

        }
    });
    /**
     * Getting Friends info
     * */
    btnShowFriends.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mAsyncRunner
                    .request("me/friends", new FriendsRequestListener());

        }
    });

    /**
     * Posting to Facebook Wall
     * */
    btnPostToWall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            postToWall();
        }
    });
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // getFriends();
            logoutFromFacebook();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}

/**
 * Function to login into facebook
 * */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void loginToFacebook() {

    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if (access_token != null) {
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);

        btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        // Making get profile button visible
        btnFbGetProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Making post to wall visible
        btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        btnShowFriends.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Making photos gallery button visible


             btnLogout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            Log.d("FB Sessions", "" + facebook.isSessionValid());
        }

    if (expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
        facebook.authorize(this,
                new String[] { "email", "publish_stream", "user_photos", "friends_photos" },
                new DialogListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // Function to handle cancel event
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                        // Function to handle complete event
                        // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                        editor = mPrefs.edit();
                        editor.putString("access_token",
                                facebook.getAccessToken());
                        editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                facebook.getAccessExpires());
                        editor.commit();

                        // Making Login button invisible
                             btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                        // Making logout Button visible
                    btnFbGetProfile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        btnShowFriends.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        // Making post to wall visible
                        btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        // Making show access tokens button visible


                        btnLogout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        getprofilepic();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(DialogError error) {
                        // Function to handle error

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                        // Function to handle Facebook errors

                    }

                });
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

/**
 * Get Profile information by making request to Facebook Graph API
 * */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void getProfileInformation() {
    mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d("Profile", response);
            String json = response;
            try {
                // Facebook Profile JSON data
                JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);

                // getting name of the user
                username = profile.getString("username");

                // getting email of the user
                final String email = profile.getString("email");

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Name: " + username + "\nEmail: " + email,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                });

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                Object state) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Function to post to facebook wall
 * */
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void postToWall() {
    // post on user's wall.
    facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Function to show Access Tokens
 * */
public void showAccessTokens() {
    String access_token = facebook.getAccessToken();

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Access Token: " + access_token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void logout() {
    if (mPrefs != null) {
        editor.remove("access_token");
        editor.remove("access_expires");
        editor.commit();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}

private class FriendsRequestListener implements RequestListener {

    String friendData;

    // Method runs when request is complete
    public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
        Log.v("", "FriendListRequestONComplete");
        // Create a copy of the response so i can be read in the run()
        // method.
        friendData = response;
        Log.v("friendData--", "" + friendData);
        // Create method to run on UI thread
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    // Parse JSON Data
                    JSONObject json;
                    json = Util.parseJson(friendData);

                    // Get the JSONArry from our response JSONObject
                    JSONArray friendArray = json.getJSONArray("data");

                    Log.v("friendArray--", "" + friendArray);

                    for (int i = 0; i < friendArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject frnd_obj = friendArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        friends_list.add("Name:"+frnd_obj.getString("name") + "  ID:"
                                + frnd_obj.getString("id"));
                    }

                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                            getBaseContext(),
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                            android.R.id.text1, friends_list);

                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FacebookError e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
            Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
            Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 public void logoutFromFacebook() {
  mAsyncRunner.logout(this, new RequestListener() {

   @Override
   public void onComplete(final String response, Object state) {
       Thread timer = new Thread() { //new thread         
            public void run() {
                Boolean b = true;
                try {

                       editor.remove("access_token");
                      editor.commit();
                     sleep(500);
                Log.d("Logout from Facebook", response);

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {  
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                           btnFbLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                           // making all remaining buttons invisible
                           btnFbGetProfile.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                           btnPostToWall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                           btnShowFriends.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                           btnLogout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                           adapter.clear();
                           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are logged out from Facebook", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });



                    while (b == true);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                }
            };
        };
        timer.start();

   }

   @Override
   public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
     Object state) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
     Object state) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
   }
  });
 }


@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void getprofilepic(){
    mAsyncRunner.request("me", new RequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
            Log.d("Profile", response);
            String json = response;

            try {

                // Facebook Profile JSON data
                final JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(json);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                // getting name of the user
                try {
                    username = profile.getString("username");
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }


try {
    img_value = new
    URL("https://graph.facebook.com/"+username+"/picture?type=normal");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Bitmap mIcon1 = null;

try {
    mIcon1 =
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(img_value.openConnection().getInputStream());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
user_picture.setImageBitmap(mIcon1); 
                    }

                });

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                    Object state) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
            }
        });

}


}
```

////
     This code to activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_fblogin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Login with Facebook" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_fb_post_to_wall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Post to Wall"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_get_profile"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Get Profile Data"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_show_friends"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Show Friends"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Logout"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

/// And add Mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.abc"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.abc.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks KamranAfsar for your Help..But Sir ...I have to post Message in Single Sign On  method..